# How to save mongodb findone value to a javascript variable to use it later on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have spent tow day to solve this problem but got nothing. All the answers in stackoverflow didn't work for me.

here is my code

```
const userCredential = require("./db").db().collection("api");
```

now I want to retrieve a doc like API to save it on a variable

```
const api = userCredential.findOne({username:'admin'}, (err, doc)=> (doc.username))
```

and now I want to use the variable to anywhere in the file. But it returned undefined.

if I try this one

```
let api;
userCredential.findOne({username:'admin'}, (err, doc)=> (api = doc.api))
```

also return undefined because of nature of Asynchronous.

How can I save in to a variable?

Comment: Here are some guidelines to use the asynchronous usage with [Promises and Callbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/) of MongoDB API.

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't help. I want to save a asynchronous value to a variable

Comment: You need to update your question post about how you want to use that variable (what is the purpose, etc.) - more details I think.

Comment: how can I save a mongodb query to a variable that I can use later. `let api;
userCredential.findOne({username:'admin'}, (err, doc)=> (api = doc.api)``console.log(api)` that returns undefined. but why and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
function query(username) {
  console.log('query');
  Test.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, result) {
    console.log('findOne callback');
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(`result: ${result}`);
      return ${result};
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this . But I want to save it to a global variable.

Comment: You can call this function wherever you want. I have changed in function like take username parameter and it returns the result